# how can I use ttl (time to live) on mongodb with collection.update?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I want to expire data in database ( its ok with expireAfterSeconds), but i want to use with collection.update>> data are always send data to database in real-time so TTL must be working on update data.. can i do that??

here is my code which i used for deleting a data from mongodb after specified time using ttl.

```
var time = "20";


MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
    var dbase = db.db("testing5");
var myobj = ({ 
    "email" : scream_email,
     "location_id" : location ,
      "trend_tags" :trends ,
      "language" : lang , 
      "createdAt" : new Date(),
      "emoji" : emoji,
       "scream_link" : scream_path , 
       "scream_type" : screamtype
     });

dbase.collection("log_events").ensureIndex({ "email": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: time ,unique:true})


  dbase.collection("log_events").insertOne(myobj, function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    resultant = result

    console.log("data inserted and will be deleted approximately after 20 seconds");
    db.close();
  });
  });
```

Comment: I use azure mongo DB for my usage. It has a configuration to define the field which may contain datetime value. Db will read the value from expireafterseconds from database and check the datetime value field in the document. Thus it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

From the [TTL Index manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/):

> To create a TTL index, use the db.collection.createIndex() method with the expireAfterSeconds option on a field whose value is either a date or an array that contains date values.

However your index creation uses `email` which I assume doesn't contain any date:

> ...ensureIndex({ "email": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: time ,unique:true})

Instead, you need to use the `createdAt` field to make the TTL index work, which I assumed contains the document's creation time:

```
...createIndex({ "createdAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: time })
```

Also, you don't want the `unique: true` constraint on the index. Otherwise, two documents inserted at exactly the same time will be disallowed by the database.

Please see [Expire Data from Collections by Setting TTL](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/) for more examples.

Note that `ensureIndex()` is an old MongoDB idiom, and is [deprecated since MongoDB 3.0](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.ensureIndex/). Use [db.collection.createIndex()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/#db.collection.createIndex) instead.